# How to not have thumbnails overlap in Finder?

Tags: finder

How can you drag thumnails around in Finder so that they can't overlap other thumbnails.

Even when "Snap To Grid" is set, thumbnails just snap on top of other ones.  I don't quite know how this would even be useful.

What I'd like is the typical thing where as you drag it to a spot it opens a hole in the grid for it to be and everything to the right of it is shifted over

Answer (score 3):

You need to have either 'Sort by' or 'Arrange By' set to something, rather than just having Snap to Grid set.
Right-click in the folder but not on an icon to see the option, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: But then I can't move and rearrange the thumbnails, which was the whole reason I was trying to get this to work

Comment: You are in an either/or situation, I'm afraid - hoping for an iOS -type solution which doesn't exist on any desktop, afaik.